# bash script to remove select files

Tags: linux, bash

I have a series of files that are named according to `field.%d.vtk` and are generated when I run a C++ code. The codes does a series of computation inside a for-loop and dumps the output whenever `i%N == 0` where `i` is the loop variable and `N` is a constant. By mistake I have set `N = 1` and now I have huge amount of data that I do not need. I also do not want to rerun the code.

How can I write a bash script to only keep every `N` files, delete the rest, and rename the remaining files such that numbers in `field.%d.vtk` are contiguous? Sorry if this is trivial, but I have very limited experience with bash scripting.

**EDIT**: When `N=1` (by mistake) range of `%d` would be in [0, 1, ..., O(100,000)] (really large) a suitable `N` is something around `N=100` which would shrink down the number of files to O(1000) or so.

Thanks

Comment: Can you [edit] and add the range of %d right now and an example of a value for N that would be suitable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If N=100 then it is pretty easy to strip them down.  The following will delete any files that don't end in 00.vtk

```
find -name '*.vtk' -not -name '*00.vtk' -exec rm {} +
```

So this would leave 100.vtk, 200.vtk etc

Then to make them contiguous, you can just strip out the 00:

```
rename 00.vtk .vtk *.vtk
```

This assumes standard posix rename.  If you have the perl rename installed it is:

```
rename 's/00.vtk/.vtk/' *.vtk
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *.vtk
do
    [[ $i =~ \.([0-9]*)\. ]] && ((BASH_REMATCH[1] % 100 != 0)) && echo $i
done
```

Change `echo` to `rm` when you've double checked this command!

Answer (score 0):

Bash( 4+)-only version of Paul's answer (so, it will only leave every 100th file .vtk file, those ending with `00.vtk`, and will rename them by stripping the `00`):

```
shopt -s extglob
rm ./!(*00).vtk
for f in ./*.vtk; do mv "$f" "${f%00.vtk}.vtk"; done
```

If you want recursiveness:

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
rm ./**/!(*00).vtk
for f in ./**/*.vtk; do mv "$f" "${f%00.vtk}.vtk"; done
```